# Why we can represent automorphisms in $\text{Gal}(\Bbb Q(\sqrt[4]{2},i)/\Bbb Q)$ as permutations in $S_4$ but not $S_8$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, automorphism-group

The splitting field of $x^4-2$ over $\Bbb Q$ is $G=\text{Gal}(\Bbb Q(\sqrt[4]{2},i)/\Bbb Q)$. By primitive element theorem, $K=\Bbb Q(\alpha)$ for some $\alpha$ and $[K:\Bbb Q]=8$. So I know that the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\Bbb Q$ has degree $8$. And at the same time there are eight automorphisms in $G$.

However, one thing I don't understand is that some authors labeled the roots $\sqrt[4]{2},~\sqrt[4]{2}i,~-\sqrt[4]{2},~-\sqrt[4]{2}i$ of $x^4-2$ as $1,~2,~3,~4$, and say that every automorphisms in $G$ can be represented as a permutation. For example, $\sigma_1=(1~~2~~3~~4)$. How can we do this? Why we can only analyze how the roots $\sqrt[4]{2},~\sqrt[4]{2}i,~-\sqrt[4]{2},~-\sqrt[4]{2}i$ is affected by the automorphism, and then we can decide it? Maybe there are **different** $\sigma,~\sigma'\in G$ such that $\forall r\in\{\sqrt[4]{2},~\sqrt[4]{2}i,~-\sqrt[4]{2},~-\sqrt[4]{2}i\},~\sigma(r)=\sigma'(r)$.

**Picture:**
[image]

Comment: $K$ is the splitting field of $X^4-2$.

Comment: Hmm... I think I must miss some critical theorems. If $K$ is the splitting field of $x^4-2$, then what will happen?

Comment: Re the (current) title: [Cayley's theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_theorem)?

Comment: @Shaun I mean maybe the numbers in the cycles will exceed 4, e.g. $(1~~3~~2~~4~~5~~7~~8~~6)$. But it seems that in this case, all cycles are using number from one to four only.

Comment: First an automorphism in the Galois group is a permutation. It sends one of the $4$ roots to an other one, so its a subgroup of $\mathrm{S}_4$. Second  $\{\sqrt[4]{2},~\sqrt[4]{2}i,~-\sqrt[4]{2},~-\sqrt[4]{2}i\}$ is a basis for the  $\Bbb Q -$vector space $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[4]{2},i)$, so the values of an automorphism on these elements will determine the automorphism.

Comment: @mouthetics Wait, $[\Bbb Q(\sqrt[4]{2},i):\Bbb Q]=8$,  how can $\{\sqrt[4]{2},~\sqrt[4]{2}i,~-\sqrt[4]{2},~-\sqrt[4]{2}i\}$ which consists of only four elements be a basis of it?

Comment: The splitting filed is generated, over the rationals, by the roots and so any automorphism in $G$ fixes the rationals and is determined its action on the roots, and must map roots to other roots, and there's only four of them. I imagine you could use another set of generators of $G$ which is invariant under G, choosing more than four if you like, and look at the action of G on them -- you'd still be looking at the same group but you'd have an embedding of it into a bigger permutation group.

Comment: The four roots do not form a vector space basis over Q, such a basis has eight elements, the simplest being the four powers of fourth root of 2 together with each of those times $i$.

Comment: Can there be two different $\sigma,~\sigma'\in G$ such that $\forall r\in\{\sqrt[4]{2},~\sqrt[4]{2}i,~-\sqrt[4]{2},~-\sqrt[4]{2}i\},~\sigma(r)=\sigma'(r)$?

Comment: Is it argued by using this [theorem](https://imgur.com/a/rsQmnew)? But I don't think the hypothesis is match.

Comment: @Shara no, the action of any automorphism in $G$ (the Galois group of the splitting field of $p(x)$) is determined but what it does to the roots of $p(x)$.

Comment: Sorry I mean a basis $\{ i, \sqrt[4]{2}\}$ for the $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra.

Comment: Actually you only need the action on the two elements $ \{ i, \sqrt[4]{2}\}$ or equivalently $ \{  \sqrt[4]{2}, i  \sqrt[4]{2}\}$

Comment: Then you extend to all the elements of the extensions.

Comment: The fact that a homomorphism is uniquely determined once we know how it maps a set of generators is everywhere in algebra. Students probably first meet this principle in linear algebra in the form: *a linear transformation is fully described when we know how it maps the elements of a basis*. Unlike in linear algebra in other structures we cannot choose the images of the generators any which way we please, but that's besides the point.

Comment: (cont'd) The four zeros generate the splitting field **as an extension field of $\Bbb{Q}$**, and therefore knowing their images determines an automorphism uniquely **if such an automorphism exists**. The latter is a separate question. Anyway, nothing stops you from finding a single generating element for this field extension, locating its eight conjugates, and rewriting the Galois group as a group of permutations of that octet.

Comment: In a sense the Galois group really is a group of permutations of $K$. But we choose to try and locate finite subsets $S\subset K$ such that A) $\sigma(S)=S$ for all the automorphisms $\sigma$, and B) the set $S$ is large enough so that restricting $\sigma$ to the subset $S$ is injective, i.e. no two automorphisms map all the elements of $S$ the same way. The way to achieve B, is to make sure that $K=\Bbb{Q}(S)$. The way to achieve A is to make sure that all conjugates of elements of $S$ are included in $S$.

Comment: So the end result is that we can study the same Galois group via its restrictions to different subsets $S$. It is usually more convenient to make $S$ as small as possble because then there is less to write down, when we describe automorphisms (or calculate their compositions), but nothing stops us from using a larger set $S$ should we want to.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I see!! Thanks!! One more little question, in this classic example, do we prefer to choose $S_1=\{\sqrt[4]{2},~\sqrt[4]{2}i,~-\sqrt[4]{2},~-\sqrt[4]{2}i\}$ or $S_2=\{\sqrt[4]{2},i\}$ (to solve the problem)? I have two textbook reference calculated and analyzed the fixed field (or Galois group) diagram by $S_1$ and $S_2$ at the same time (like the figure in my post). Is it somewhat redundant? Hmm, I feel the first and second columns can be deleted (because it won't be used if we consider the problem via $S_1$). Or alternatively, the third column could be deleted.

Comment: They both have their use. $S_1$ is stable under the action of the Galois group, and that is needed to realize the Galois group as a subgroup of $S_4$. $S_2$ works better when getting a census of the automorphisms. We know that there will be eight of them. $\root4\of2$ has four possible automorphic images, $i$ has two. $2\cdot4=8$ so we can conclude that all eight combinations all occur exactly once (because $S_2$ generates the spitting field each combo occurs at most once).

Comment: literally the previous problem in the [tag:galois-theory] tag: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3056994/328173

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen The comment box is not your lecture room; maybe you should make it an answer.

Comment: @KennyLau It is a moral certainty that this particular Galois group has been handled many times already. And, unlike certain others, I won't knowingly post an answer to a duplicate. You can make a case that my comments would work better in, say, a chatroom. My goal is to have the asker post an answer, after a bit of prodding, but such goals may be difficult to reach. If you think my comments should be removed, you can flag them as obsolete.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I see!! Thanks! And to determine which $\sigma_i$'s forms a proper nontrivial subgroup of $\text{Gal}(K/\Bbb Q)$, it is quicker and more convenient to compute through cycles in subgroup of $S_4$. To see this via viewing these as $\begin{cases}\sigma_1(\sqrt[4]{2})=\sqrt[4]{2}i\\\sigma_1(i)=i\end{cases}$, $\begin{cases}\sigma_2(\sqrt[4]{2})=-\sqrt[4]{2}\\\sigma_2(i)=i\end{cases}$ and finally figure out that, say, $\{\text{id},\sigma_2,\sigma_4,\sigma_6\}$, is a proper subgroup of it will be a hard job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that if $F$ is the ground field, and $p(x)$ is an **irreducible** polynomial over $F$ of degree $n\geq 1$ without repeated roots, let $K$ be the splitting field of $p(x)$. $K/F$ is Galois. You have that the Galois group of $K/F$, say $G$, it is embedded on $S_n$, this is because $G$ permutes the roots.

In your problem, $F=\mathbb{Q}$ and $K$ is the splitting field of $p(x)=x^4-2$, since its roots are $\sqrt[4]{2}$, $-\sqrt[4]{2}$, $i\sqrt[4]{2}$, $-i\sqrt[4]{2}$.

For a better understanding. The Galois group acts transitively on the roots of that polynomial (it is important the irreducibility). If you are not clear about the Galois group yet, you can take intermediate fields, study the irredubile polynomial on the tower of fields and you will know that the Galois Group in some extension of the tower of fields acts transitively on the root and fix the elements on the base field. For example, in this case, if you want to use that method, consider the tower of fields $\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt[4]{2},i\right)\supset\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt[4]{2}\right)\supset \mathbb{Q}$, since $\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt[4]{2},i\right)/\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt[4]{2}\right)$ is Galois (splitting field of $x^2+1$), you know now that theres is a $\sigma$ in $\mbox{Gal}\left(\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt[4]{2},i\right)/\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt[4]{2}\right)\right)$ such that send $i\mapsto -i$ (acts on the roots of $x^2+1$) and leave $\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt[4]{2}\right)$ fixed, but the Galois group of that extension if a subgroup of the Galois group of $K/\mathbb{Q}$, so $\sigma$ lie to $\mbox{Gal}\left(K/\mathbb{Q}\right)$

Comment: I did an incomplete answer at the end, because I thought that is was enough for you. But, if you need more help I can add more detailed information of comment here

Comment: But generally the analysis is always done first in the group-world, and then pull back to see its related fixed field right?

Comment: Hm, depends of the facts you know about the group or the extension. I will give you two examples. First, if the extension is given by a splitting field of a polynomial of degree $n$, and the extension have degree $n!$, then the galois group is the symmetric group of order $n!$ (the galois group order equals the order of the galois extension). Second, the extension obtained from a cyclotomic polynomial, for instance, the splitting field of $x^p-1$ where $p$ is a prime number, you will get easily that the if we consider $\zeta$ one generator (a finite subset of a field is cylic)

Comment: ...of the groups of roots of that polynomials, then an element of the galois group and their powers acting on $\zeta$ will leave to that the galois group embedds on the set of units of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ (the argument works for any positive integer in fact)